# Binary value in WHERE clause (Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to select rows with a binary value in the WHERE clause.
The binary value is in HEX: "07F4"

The following HQL Statement doesn't work ("unexpected token X").

```
from Agprfw where prfdatk1 = X'07F4'
```

Comment: `where prfdatk1 = '0x07F4'` or `where prfdatk1 = 0x07F4` is working?

Comment: For ['0x07F4'] I get 0 rows, which isn't true.
For [0x07F4] I get an exception (NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x07F4").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
from Agprfw where HEX(prfdatk1) = '07F4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] param = new byte[]{ 0x07, 0xf4};
List<Agprfw> rslt = em.createQuery("from Agprfw a where a.prfdatk1 = :b", Agprfw.class)
         .setParameter("b", param)
         .getResultList();
```

Referencing the column as `alias.column` is important in JPQL, so don't skip it.